# Making a memory card flipping game in C++

Tags: c++, error-handling, compiler-errors

I need some help with this program:

Write a program that presents the backs of a number of cards to the player. You should have at
least 10 cards. The player selects 2 cards (one at a time), if they match, the player gets a point and
the cards remain face up. If they do not match, the cards must turn back over. The game continues
until all cards have been turned over.

I wrote most of the program but it didn't work out. I don't know how to check if the pairs of cards is match or not but I am trying to do it.

Here my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <Windows.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    
    int row1, column1, row2, column2, board[2][5];

    int choiceBoard[2][5] =
    {
        {0,1,2,3,4},
        {5,6,7,8,9}
    };

    char displayBoard[2][5] =
    {
        {'0','1','2','3','4'},
        {'5','6','7','8','9'}
    };

    char displayLetter[2][5] =
    {
        {'A','B','C','D','E'},
        {'E','D','C','B','A'}
    };

    int firstChoice;
    int secondChoice;

    bool playing = true;

    while (playing)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++)
            {
                cout << "[" << displayBoard[row][column] << "]";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }


        cout << "Choose a card to reveal it: ";
        cin >> firstChoice;

        for (row1 = 0; row1 < 2; row1++) {
            for (column1 = 0; column1 < 5; column1++) {
                if (choiceBoard[row1][column1] == firstChoice) {
                    displayBoard[row1][column1] = displayLetter[row1][column1];
                }
            }
        }

        cout << "Choose another card to reveal it: ";
        cin >> secondChoice;

        for (row2 = 0; row2 < 2; row2++) {
            for (column2 = 0; column2 < 5; column2++) {
                if (choiceBoard[row2][column2] == secondChoice) {
                    displayBoard[row2][column2] = displayLetter[row2][column2];
                }
            }
        }

        if (board[row1][column1] == board[row2][column2]) {
            cout << "Match!" << endl;
            Sleep(2000);
        }
        else {
            cout << "Card do not match!" << endl;
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        
        system("cls");

        
        if (firstChoice == secondChoice)
        {
            cout << "Error..." << endl;
            playing = false;
            
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. I am afraid, I don't know what to look for. What exactly 'does not work'? You put the tag 'compiler-errors', so what errors are you getting? Please consider posting an [mre] describing the problem you are having.

Comment: There are definitely issues in your code but I couldn't find a compiler error: [test on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b98660c9979b2801). You have to use a debugger to sort this out. Btw. the warning is interesting. I needed a bit to see why the compiler can know this. Finally, I realized the compiler is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what these boards' functions are, but if you want to judge if the selected pair is match, you can try this:

```
if (displayLetter[firstChoice / 5][firstChoice % 5] == displayLetter[secondChoice / 5][secondChoice % 5]) {
            cout << "Match!" << endl;
            Sleep(2000);
        }
```

Then you can change the display content, I don't think some of the for-loops are necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I need.